# Calculating the hexadecimal of the elements of a string/array and then convert these to decimal

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a UI designed with wxwidgets in which I enter a user name. I want the hexadecimal sum of all the elements which would then to be converted to decimal. This is what I have done:

```
wxArrayString TextAlia = wxT("");//declared global

    TextBox1 = new wxTextCtrl(this, TEXT_BOX1, wxT(""), wxPoint(300, 10), wxSize(100, 20), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER | wxTE_PROCESS_TAB | wxTE_LEFT, wxDefaultValidator, wxT("WxTextBox"));


void MyFrame::OnGenerateKey(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event)) {
int i;
char name[i];

TextAlia = TextBox1->GetValue();

i = strlen(TextAlia);
for (i = 0; i < strlen(TextAlia); i++) {


char buffer[3];char Temp[3];

_itoa( name[i], buffer, 16 );

 }
```

This is what I have tried to do please help me.

What now id did is :

```
int lengtharray = sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]);

for (int j=0; j<lengtharray; j++)
{
   name[j] = ?//i need to write something here so that the name[1] is changed to 45 for     
  capital "E"
  // avariable may be of type hex just like sum that keeps on incrementing the value

}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the username? It's not clear.

Comment: What i want with user name is that the characters of the user name must be changed to the hex values and then there should be a sum of these hex values

Comment: You want to take the numeric representation of each letter, and sum them together? So e.g. `"abc"` is  `97 98 99`, and the sum is `294`.

Comment: you got it right "a" is 61 in hexa so i want to have a =61h b = 62h,c=63h add them 186h and then convert it to decimal 390

Comment: You could just add them up (char[0] + char[1] + ...), and then printf to a string. string a; printf(a, "Hex: %X, Dec: %d", sum, sum);

Comment: Why did you do `i = strlen(TextAlia);
for (i = 0; i < strlen(TextAlia); i++)`?

Comment: @Emma - A `char` already *is* a small integer containing the (ASCII) code for the character, the difference is in how we chose to display it.

Comment: @A_nto2 i need to calculate the length of the string so that i could add them according to a for loop

Comment: @EmmaRochweel: Isn't better to do `int len = strlen(TextAlia); for (i = 0; i < len; i++)`? ;)

Comment: oh yes however i already have int i declared global

Comment: @EmmaRochweel: Emma, `i = strlen(TextAlia);` , as it is, is useless.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to sum the number representation of characters in a string. I'm not familiar with wxwidgets, I think it uses its own string type, but I'll show how to do it with c-style strings and c++ `std::string`s. The first thing to note is that `char` is just a numeric type able to store at least the numbers 0 to 127. You can use it directly in a sum. It's just when you print it out it gets turned into recognisable letters.

I've pasted a simple program here: http://ideone.com/dqIE5 with two functions that show how to loop over characters in a string and sum them. In both cases you just have a loop over the characters, adding to a running sum.

There are also several errors in the code you show. First:

```
int i;
char name[i];
```

There are two mistakes here. You try to use `i` without initialising it (giving it a value). How big do you expect `name` to be? Second, the size of an array must be a constant, known at compile time. So you could do something like

```
const int i = 10;
char name[i];
```

Another probable mistake:

```
i = strlen(TextAlia);
for (i = 0; i < strlen(TextAlia); i++) {
```

You set `i` to the length of `TextAlia` and then immediately set it to `0`. Then call `strlen` over and over. Perhaps you want:

```
int length = strlen(TextAlia);
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = strlen(TextAlia);
int sum = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
    sum += TextAlia[j]
}

char* a = new char[40];
sprintf(a, "%d", sum); // decimal value
sprintf(a, "%x", sum); // hexadecimal value
```

Comment: You mean `sum += name[j]`. The downfall of obscure variable naming.

Comment: @Anton Roth:You see i dont understand  why have u written name[j] i have the character string in the TextAliaso why name[i]

Comment: True, I had it with her i=0 at first, and then thought, bad naming, I'll change the for loop to j, and forgot to change the name[i]. Thx for the pointer. As for the name vs TextAlia, my bad, I did not really read the code, and thought it was in name... changed answer accordingly.